# How to get values from association table using ID?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

First of all i don't know whether the title is relevant or not (please forgive me if it's not relavant).

I have 2 tables `userprofile` and `country`.

```
userprofile table:-
-----------------------------------------
userid | email |............|**countryid**
-----------------------------------------

country table:-
-----------------------------------------
**countryid** | countryname
-----------------------------------------
```

I want to select data from the userpfofile table, 
i.e  `$query="select * from userprofile` ...but the problem is that this data returns countryid but I actually want to return countryname.

I am new to MySQL, so please suggest the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) these two tables together to get the data you want, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM userprofile u
    LEFT JOIN country c
    ON c.countryid = u.countryid
```

This will produce a result set similar to:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| userid | email | .......... | countryid | countryname |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Tip: if the name of the column is the same in both table, you can use `USING`like this: `SELECT * FROM userprofile  LEFT JOIN country USING countryid`

Comment: whats wrong with a normal join (for a noob) SELECT * FROM userprofile, country WHERE userprofile.countryid = country.countryid

Comment: @Waygood: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: @Waygood A normal join will only get you userprofiles that have a corresponding countryId.  A left join will bring back all users, even if they don't have a corresponding countryId.